# All the points in the plane are coloured using 3 colours

Tags: geometry

All the points in the plane are coloured using 3 colours. Prove that there exists a triangle with vertices having the same color such that either it is isosceles or its angles are in geometric progression

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1759758/coloring-problem-with-equilateral-triangles/1759782#1759782 which proves that there is an equilateral triangle with vertices the same colour.

Comment: ok ok but how can u clarify the GP part

Comment: Any equilateral triangle is isosceles and also has its angles in geometric progression.